# Matrix field entry link corrupted

Tags: matrix, field, error, link

Some of my links coming from a matrix field with entry became corrupted. Anyone had this before and knows how to fix it?
[image: admin field]
[image: entry]
[image: corrupted link]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to output an unexecuted Element Query. Please can you add your template code responsible for this output and we'll help explain how best to fix.

Comment: I added it. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting an unexecuted [Element Query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html). To clarify - the thing stored in your Entries field named `buttonLink` is not a Craft entry as you might expect, but is basically a raw unexecuted database query (that will fetch the selected entry once executed). In Craft 3 those unexecuted queries automatically got executed if you attempt to output them, but they should throw deprecation errors in the control panel (Utilities > Deprecation Errors). In Craft 4 you can't get away with that anymore.

The quick and easy solution is to execute the query. There are a few ways to execute queries: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries

But really, the "proper" solution here is to add some [eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) so that all your child queries are combined into the queries used to fetch the parent matrix block(s). This is significantly more performant, especially if you're outputting multiple matrix blocks (though I see from your code you're only outputting one).

Here's how eager loading might look for your code:

```
{% set button = cta.button.with('buttonLink').one() %}
<a href="{{ button.buttonLink[0].url }}"><div class="button">{{ button.buttonText }}</div></a>
```

Or without eager loading (don't do this):

```
{% set button = cta.button.one() %}
<a href="{{ button.buttonLink.one().url }}"><div class="button">{{ button.buttonText }}</div></a>
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your answer!