# How to get the image from the last matrix block using twig's last filter

Tags: matrix, craft4

I am on Craft CMS version 4.0.4. I used the `last` filter to get the last matrix, but when I tried to get the image, I kept getting an error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("image") on a string variable
> ("}").

Here's my code

```
{% set lastBlock = entry.homeHeroBanner|last %}
{% set lastImage = lastBlock.image.first() %}
```

Anyone know how to get the image from the last matrix block?

Answer (score 1):

Found how to do it on Craft 4.

```
{% set numberOfBlocks = entry.homeHeroBanner.count() %}
{% set lastBlock = entry.homeHeroBanner.all()[numberOfBlocks - 1] %}
{% set lastImage = lastBlock.backgroundImage.one() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original (Craft 3?) code should have been throwing deprecation errors in the control panel (Utilities > Deprecation Errors), because you haven't executed your Element Query (`entry.homeHeroBanner`). It should be:

```
{% set lastBlock = entry.homeHeroBanner.all()|last %}
or: {% set lastBlock = entry.homeHeroBanner.inReverse().one() %}

{% set lastImage = lastBlock.image.one() %}
```

or preferably, with Eager Loading:

```
{% set lastBlock = entry.homeHeroBanner.with('image').all()|last %}
{% set lastImage = lastBlock.image[0] %}
```

Strangely enough I answered the same question yesterday - here's a more complete explanation: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/39528/271

Before upgrading to Craft 4 be sure to correct any deprecation errors.